# Change NavBar on HomePage when using React-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-dom

All I want to do is have a different Navbar for the home page and a different one for the rest of the pages. I have used things like `window.location.pathname` and also `withRouter`. These things only work when the page reloads. When using `Link` and navigate to a new page from Home, the Navbar of the Home page remains on the other pages until I reload and vice versa.

What worked for me is using

`useEffect(()=> { document.getElementById("id of home nav").style.display = "none" document.getElementById("id of regular nav").style.display = "block" },[]}`

But, I have to do this on every single Component page. I wonder if there is a better way to do this. Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
This is what I have tried now

"/HomeNavbar.jsx"

```
  return (
    <>
      {window.location.pathname === "/" ? (
        "Home Navbar Code Here"
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

So when I traverse from other pages to the home page this works perfectly. I wrote a similar code in my regular Navbar but am having the same issues again. The navbar only loads once I reload my page.

"/RegularNavbar.jsx"

```
return (
    <>
      {window.location.pathname === "/" ? null : (
       "Regular Navbar code Here"
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is the Navbar a React component as well?

Comment: Yes sir. I put it on top of the components within Browser Router so it appears on all the pages. The Id is of the main container of the Nav where I apply my CSS.

Comment: Please share the whole code

Comment: There is a lot of code as such. Can you specify what code do you want to look at @ShivangGupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two different layouts (higher order components) with different navbars and wrap the home page with layout1 and other components with layout 2

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const Layout1 = (props) => (
  <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <div>{props.children}</div>
  </div>
);

export default Layout1;
```

layout 2:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const Layout2 = (props) => (
  <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topicgdfgdgs</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <p>this is a different nav bar, different from the home page</p>
      <div>{props.children}</div>
      <hr/>
  </div>
);

export default Layout2;
```

home component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout1 from '../Layouts/Layout1';
const Home = () => (
  <Layout1>
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  </Layout1>
);

export default Home;
```

any other components:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout2 from '../Layouts/Layout2';

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <Layout2>
    <div>
      <h3>topics</h3>
    </div>
  </Layout2>
);

export default Topics;
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter-2jzbru?file=components%2FTopics.js)

Comment: Hey man your answer worked amazingly well. But, whether I like it or not, I will have to enclose my return statement withing <Layout1 or Layout2>? Like is there a way that I do it just once and it works everywhere? Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @damndaniel2000 Yes, you can create two higher order components which contain navigation bars and the Route component from react-router. And use them on your routing. First layout on your main route, the second on other
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-starter-y1kcz2?file=components%2FMainNavRoute.js
Stackblitz example. Look on  MainNavRoute file and OtherNav route file and how i use them into index.js file.

Comment: Just saw it. Its something new for me but it worked. Can you tell me what do these lines mean - `const OtherNavRoute = ({component: Component,...rest}) => {`
   and `<Route {...rest} render={(props)=>{`